# multiple patterns with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

My situation is: I'm processing an array word by word. What I'm hoping to do and
working on, is to capture a certain word. But for that I need to test two patterns or more with preg-match.

This is my code :

```
function search_array($array)
{
$pattern  = '[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{1,3}[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]?';
$pattern2 = '[A-Z]{1,7}[0-9]{1,2}';
$patterns = array($pattern, $pattern2); 
$regex = '/(' .implode('|', $patterns) .')/i'; 
foreach ($array as $str) {
  if (preg_match ($regex, $str, $m)){
    $matches[] = $m[1];
    return $matches[0]; 
  }
 }
}
```

Example of array I could have  :

```
Array ( [0] => X [1] => XXXXXXX [2] => XXX [3] => XXXX [4] => ABC01DC4 )

Array ( [0] => X [1] => XXXXXXX [2] => XXX [3] => ABCDEF4 [4] => XXXX [5] => XX )
```

Words I would like to catch :

```
-In the first array  : ABC01DC4

-In the second array : ABCDEF4
```

The problem is not the pattern itself, it's the syntax to use multiple pattern in the same pregmatch

Comment: Um... do you have a question?

Comment: Kindly elaborate with an example of the input and the output you want to achieve.

Comment: Well, [passing an array containing the string `A1` returns `A1`](http://ideone.com/ABXk9U). So... what gives?

Comment: I apologize for my oversight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code worked with me, and I didn't find any problem with the code or the REGEX. Furthermore, the description you provided is not enough to understand your needs.

However, I have guessed one problem after observing your code, which is, you didn't use any [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)(`^...$`) to perform matching the whole string. Your regex can find match for these inputs: `%ABC01DC4V` or `ABCDEF4EE`. So change this line with your code:

```
$regex = '/^(' .implode('|', $patterns) .')$/i'; 
          -+-                             -+-
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry for my post, I'm a beginner in english :)
Do you know how I could limit the length inside the pregmatch ? For example the word must be inferior to 7 letters.

Comment: @musecz if the letters are exactly 7 characters in length then `[a-z]{7}` if its 7 or more then `[a-z]{7,}`

Comment: A last thing lol : Imagine This situation [0] => (ABCDEF4/xxxx/xxx) ; Do you know how I could get 'ABCDEF4' with a regex in this situation

Comment: That case you have to remove the `$` sign to open up the right side of the string. For example `^([A-Z]{1,7}[0-9]{1,2})`